# Is it possible to save binary metadata to photos in iOS Photo Library?

Tags: ios, metadata

All the examples of saving metadata I've found involve numbers or short strings. I'd like to store a few thousand bytes. I could use base64 if I can't store binary - is there a size limit?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but is anything wrong with the method `-[ALAsset – writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:]`?  You can try adding your NSData object to the metadata dictionary.   See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:

Comment: "I'd like to store a few thousand bytes" Go ahead and see what happens!

Comment: There should not be a size limit - iPhone 4S/5 photos are almost 8MB in size if full resolution. A few KB won't hurt - just remember that base64 encoding bloats data by a 4:3 ratio :) But it should not be a problem